# VS Code autocomplete for Plotly Dash with Kite

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly-dash

Been using lately VS Code with the MS Python extension and also the Kite extension. Kite works extremely fine with most Python libraries, however for the dash library autocomplete does not work and suggestions are not available for auto complete. Is this and issue with Kite? Are there alternatives for Kite?

Comment: You could always use default vs code text completion engine - Jedi. However, I suggest turning Jedi off in the settings, then vs code will automatically download and install Microsoft language server for python, which I'm personally using. It is still being actively developed, so there are shortcomings and bugs here and there, but overall it provides a very solid experience.

Comment: Hi, I work for Kite. Apologies for this inconvenience! We expect Kite to work with the dash library, so this is likely a bug. We'd appreciate your help in reporting this issue with your Kite logs on our public issue tracker on Github: https://github.com/kiteco/issue-tracker